# How can I access a fields_for object's association's methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having difficult accessing a fields_for object's association's methods in a deeply nested form. can you help me understand where i am going wrong?

Opportunity model:

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seedlings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seedlings
end
```

Seedling model:

```
class Seedling < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :opportunity
  belongs_to :potential_building
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_building
end
```

PotentialBuilding model:

```
class PotentialBuilding < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seedlings
end
```

i was hoping i could write the name of the potential_building beside the hidden_field, but i clearly am not understanding something. i can write the potential_building_id to the page, like so (haml):

```
...
= opportunity_form.fields_for :seedlings do |seedling_form|
  = seedling_form.hidden_field :potential_building_id
  = seedling_form.object.potential_building_id # => 73
....
```

i was hoping accessing the association's methods would be as easy as this, and i don't understand why it isn't.

```
...
= opportunity_form.fields_for :seedlings do |seedling_form|
  = seedling_form.hidden_field :potential_building_id
  = seedling_form.object.potential_building.name # => undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
...
```

can you help me understand? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seedlings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seedlings
end
```

http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/